# grails spring security load ip restriction entries from database

Tags: grails, spring-security

Is there a way to configure `grails.plugin.springsecurity.ipRestrictions` from database like loading Requestmap entries?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The ip restriction is implemented using a servlet filter `IpAddressFilter` which is provided by the plugin. There is no built in way to load ip restrictions from database. However  you should be able to create a custom filter which extends the `IpAddressFilter` or `GenericFilterBean` and override the spring bean with name `ipAddressFilter` to implement the authorization yourself as per your requirement.

See [IpAddressFilter](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/springsecurity/web/filter/IpAddressFilter.groovy) class